# iMacros: Display a dialog or play sound on macro error

Tags: google-chrome, imacros

I have a macro running on a unmanned computer and need to check it every now and then when it errors (usually due to the page becoming unresponsive and needs a refresh).
It would be very handy if i could script in a windows dialog or play a sound when the macros stops due to error so i could easily realise if there is an error that needs resolving.

Is there a way to do this?

Using iMacros chrome extension VERSION BUILD=7020226 in Windows 7

Comment: Yes. Use javacsript scripting, then use try catch method. If script catches error alert error. The alert box gives a sound.

Comment: Can you please show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to run the JS iMacros code bellow for 100 times.

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 100"+"\n";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:some_class"+"\n";


for(var i=1;i<=100;i++)
{

try
{

var ret=iimPlay(macro);

}
catch(err)
{
alert("Error has happend: "+err)
}



}
```

If error happens on this type of macro then you will see alert but and hear the sound. Increase the volume on speakers. For more reference check my profile. It has a lot about iMacros, JavaScript.